# How to configure editor preferences by project in IntelliJ IDEA 13?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Currently I'm working in two project with different code style guidelines. As far as I see the editor preferences are global in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.14, for instance tabs vs. spaces.

So, is there any way where those settings can be defined by project and not globally?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different styles for the different projects. Select in the settings the "Project" profile and copy one of the different styles to the project style. (You have to click "Manage" in the code settings)
This is the only way I know, it would be nice if it would be more convenient.